# how to best layout a listview above two buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, layout

In context of the attached image (as a concept, my actual list has single text field),

I've a list view that I want to constraint to the top and constraint two buttons to the bottom (side by side), what's the best way to achieve the constraints?

**Problem:** I've some items hidden under both Support Action Bar and the buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="@string/done" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cancel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></ListView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/done"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:text="@string/ok"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cancel" />
```

Comment: There's a WYSIWYG editor in Android Studio. You can draw the connections you need.

Comment: The problem is what constraints to put. I need some advice, someone asked me to place a guideline between listview and the button, and then constraints from there,

Comment: ListView's top, start, and end to parent start, top, and end. ListView's Bottom to the top of either button. Left button start to parent start and bottom to parent bottom. Left button end to right button start. Right button end to parent end and bottom to parent bottom. 0dp width and height for ListView. Buttons should use wrap_content for height and either wrap_content or 0dp for width, depending on the look you want.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, I appreciate, can you please try this on android and post the solution code, just want to ensure I got everything right, thanks again.

Comment: Can't you just put it in and see if it works, just as easily as I can?

Comment: @Tenfour04 see my edit plesae, `layout_height="0dp"` hides everything, can't see list. Also i see list items scrolling behind the buttons.

Comment: You didn't constrain the bottom of the ListView to the top of one of the buttons or make its height 0dp

Comment: `constrain the bottom to the top of one of the buttons`, didn't get you, i'm new to this

Comment: You should not have to create a margin for the action bar.

Comment: For the ListView: `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cancel"`. You want the bottom of your list view to be aligned to the top of one of your buttons so they don't overlap.

Comment: fixed, please review the lisView, also when you say i don't have to create margin for the action bar, it's handled automatically, the list looks good now.

Comment: how to give some breathing room between `listview` and `cancel` button?

Comment: `android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"` on the ListView.

Comment: If you have something going behind your ActionBar, there might be something odd about how you're adding this layout to your Activity/Fragment. Like maybe you are using a Theme with no action bar and manually putting a Toolbar in your layout and have it overlaying the FrameLayout that you put your fragment in.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help, it's much better layout than using guidelines.